# Google Chrome and Certificate Problem

Tags: certificates, google, chrome

When I try to connect google.com and youtube.com with Chrome, I got the error below;

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.google.com.tr (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Subject: *.google.com
Issuer: Google Internet Authority G2
Expires on: Aug 23, 2017
Current date: Jun 11, 2017
PEM encoded chain:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEKDCCAxCgAwIBAgIQAQAhJYiw+lmnd+8Fe2Yn3zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBC
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEWMBQGA1UEChMNR2VvVHJ1c3QgSW5jLjEbMBkGA1UEAxMS
R2VvVHJ1c3QgR2xvYmFsIENBMB4XDTE3MDUyMjExMzIzN1oXDTE4MTIzMTIzNTk1
OVowSTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAoTCkdvb2dsZSBJbmMxJTAjBgNVBAMT
HEdvb2dsZSBJbnRlcm5ldCBBdXRob3JpdHkgRzIwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUA
A4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCcKgR3XNhQkToGo4Lg2FBIvIk/8RlwGohGfuCPxfGJziHu
Wv5hDbcyRImgdAtTT1WkzoJile7rWV/G4QWAEsRelD+8W0g49FP3JOb7kekVxM/0
Uw30SvyfVN59vqBrb4fA0FAfKDADQNoIc1Fsf/86PKc3Bo69SxEE630k3ub5/DFx
+5TVYPMuSq9C0svqxGoassxT3RVLix/IGWEfzZ2oPmMrhDVpZYTIGcVGIvhTlb7j
gEoQxirsupcgEcc5mRAEoPBhepUljE5SdeK27QjKFPzOImqzTs9GA5eXA37Asd57
r0Uzz7o+cbfe9CUlwg01iZ2d+w4ReYkeN8WvjnJpAgMBAAGjggERMIIBDTAfBgNV
HSMEGDAWgBTAephojYn7qwVkDBF9qn1luMrMTjAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUSt0GFhu89mi1
dvWBtrtiGrpagS8wDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMC4GCCsGAQUFBwEBBCIwIDAeBggr
BgEFBQcwAYYSaHR0cDovL2cuc3ltY2QuY29tMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAw
NQYDVR0fBC4wLDAqoCigJoYkaHR0cDovL2cuc3ltY2IuY29tL2NybHMvZ3RnbG9i
YWwuY3JsMCEGA1UdIAQaMBgwDAYKKwYBBAHWeQIFATAIBgZngQwBAgIwHQYDVR0l
BBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQDKSeWs
12Rkd1u+cfrP9B4jx5ppY1Rf60zWGSgjZGaOHMeHgGRfBIsmr5jfCnC8vBk97nsz
qX+99AXUcLsFJnnqmseYuQcZZTTMPOk/xQH6bwx+23pwXEz+LQDwyr4tjrSogPsB
E4jLnD/lu3fKOmc2887VJwJyQ6C9bgLxRwVxPgFZ6RGeGvOED4Cmong1L7bHon8X
fOGLVq7uZ4hRJzBgpWJSwzfVO+qFKgE4h6LPcK2kesnE58rF2rwjMvL+GMJ74N87
L9TQEOaWTPtEtyFkDbkAlDASJodYmDkFOA/MgkgMCkdm7r+0X8T/cKjhf4t5K7hl
MqO5tzHpCvX2HzLc
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Automatically report details of possible security incidents to Google. Privacy policy
ReloadHIDE ADVANCED
www.google.com.tr normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to www.google.com.tr this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be www.google.com.tr, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.

You cannot visit www.google.com.tr right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later. Learn more.
```

I have no problem at all with Firefox, Edge etc, only with Google Chrome. I have tried to install Chrome Canary, it was working without any problem for a few minutes then it starts to give the very same error as above.

Strangely, Chrome starts working again, then it stopped working again!

By the way, I have a VPN addon on chrome, it stops working too :(

- Date and Time is correct
- I have no antivirus installed, just Comodo Firewall. I closed the firewall, the same problem continued.
- I have installed MalwareByte to check if I have any, no malware.

What could be going on?

NOTE: I got a crack: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Zzx1ai0_Xs&feature=youtu.be

this happens because there is chrome task manager icon. when I remove it, the problem solves itself as you see in youtube video. why could be this happening?

Comment: The subject on the cert is *.google.com which doesn't seem to apply to google.com.tr

Comment: @iain: the CN of the cert for google.com.tr is actually *.google.com. But it has lots of subject alternative names including one for google.com.tr. And it did not complain about the name  but about an invalid certificate authority

Comment: @Oray: this looks like a bug for me. The certificates themselves look fine.

Comment: @Steffen: is it normal to see "Expires on: Aug 23, 2017
Current date: Jun 11, 2017" ?

Comment: @pcalkins: For a question asked on Jun 11, 2017 this is pretty normal.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is simply stupid, this issue is most likely caused by a time mismatch between the server and your machine. Check the time on your host and reconfigure NTP client to pull the time from the internet. I have experienced this issue in the past with a windows tablet device that had battery issue and was not keeping the date and time when the battery was fully depleeted.

You can use flow graph to view more details on the handshake and ssl negotiation to know more precisely what is the issue, although it is most likely time orientned. Alternatively you can debug your connection with OpenSSL if you have it installed on your machine:
`openssl s_client -debug -connect google.com.tr:443 -tls1_2`

Answer (score -3):

So the owners or your router that you've connected to, it shows all ip's that has been connected to on the main router and someone or you didn't know has it on blocked to unaccess to the web pages.

If it's your router then fix it to where you can make that ip on the router gain access to the YouTube, gmail, or other websites again. It has been you or someone that's blocked it. Almost 90% if you cant fix it with the time and other simple fixable problems, then first you need to ask to (or you) login to your (owners) router, then a list of ip's that will pop up, and find that you ip that's blocking it. Then somewhere there should be a section to unblock it.

Not all routers are all the same, so that info need you kinda got to find on your own, but it shouldn't be that hard tho. Play around to find it and it'll eventually unblock

Sometimes there are reasons for it being blocked, but you need to ask or not, just use a vpn, it works for me. Test them and see what works. If the vpn or time thing does not work, then you need the router to unblock it. That's the only way.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to have issues reaching the website per se, rather is concerned about the fact it appears to present an invalid certificate - using a VPN might help, but if you mention checking the local access point/router, then it would be worth recommending at least validating DNS settings.

Comment: It is most likely presenting the correct certificate but the issue is actually establishing the session. OP can parse the certificate with open ssl `openssl x509 -in infile -noout -text` to see if the certificate is correct. He can also use the developer tools and flow graph to establish what causing the issue or debug ssl with openssl.